# Setting up SSL security in spring boot 2.0.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keystore, application.properties

In earlier spring boot, the  configuration for setting up SSL security had to be done on application.properties by mentioning

```
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:shq.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-password=******
```

Would the same work on spring boot 2.0.3

If not what has to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your question is YES.

It is same for Spring boot 2.0.x versions also.

you can refer below to cross verify the same.

[Enable HTTPS with self-signed certificate in Spring Boot 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324700/enable-https-with-self-signed-certificate-in-spring-boot-2-0)