# Nio2Endpoint.Nio2SocketWrapper.getSslSupport Exception in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I implemented a self-signed ssl certificate for a the spring boot application. Although the results are coming as expected, I getting the below exception is thrown.
Using Springboot: 2.1.8 and Tomcat: 9.0.24

I tried changing the protocol from 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol' with 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'. But still getting the exception.

The exception thats thrown.

```
@Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcatServletWebServerFactory.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol");
        return tomcatServletWebServerFactory;
    }
```

```
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper.getSslSupport(Nio2Endpoint.java:1581) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1685) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$HandshakeReadCompletionHandler.failed(SecureNio2Channel.java:104) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$HandshakeReadCompletionHandler.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$HandshakeReadCompletionHandler.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005691/how-to-fix-http11nioprotocol-error-reading-request-ignored#comment102453824_58005691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [known bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63706) in Tomcat 9.0.24. It is triggered when you try and use plain text on an TLS enabled connector. The bug is fixed in the recently released 9.0.26.

Comment: Yes. I found the same in the in Bugzilla. But currently after upgrading to tomcat 9.0.26 , and when I try to execute the Jar that is created I am getting 'The port may already be in use or the connector' exception. This is only happening while executing the jar and not through bootRun.

Comment: This is happening only with 9.0.26 tomcat. The same code is working fine with 9.0.24. Not sure why?