# Spring boot Embedded tomcat throwing Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am using the Embedded Tomcat in a STS application. Suddenly, the server is throwing an error when tried hitting an API. The Error logs are as below.No new changes were made for the tomcat configurations either.

```
10:26:20.319 [https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Error reading request, ignored
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1392)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1593)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:26:20.319 [https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-2] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Error reading request, ignored
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.getSslSupport(NioEndpoint.java:1392)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1593)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:26:20.321 [https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-2] ERROR o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - Error running socket processor
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.recycle(Http11InputBuffer.java:265)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1331)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:1055)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:1023)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1593)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:26:20.321 [https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-1] ERROR o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - Error running socket processor
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.recycle(Http11InputBuffer.java:265)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1331)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:1055)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:1023)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1593)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:30:07.615 [https-jsse-nio-8090-exec-4] ERROR o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Error reading r
```

Comment: This looks known bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63706. Try to update your Spring boot version

Comment: which spring boot version you are using ??

Comment: The version used is 2.1.8

Comment: @BindumaliniKK Are you getting this error only for particular URL ?

Comment: @BindumaliniKK try to downgraded Spring boot to 2.1.4.RELEASE, it will help you

Comment: @AvijitBarua No, I changed the url from http to https.Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005691/how-to-fix-http11nioprotocol-error-reading-request-ignored) ,it's been said that this error occured due to bug in tomcat version. Try updating your tomcat by updating maven repository. After that if you face error, try specifing tomcat version.