# Conditional enabling of HTTPS in Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I would like to enable or disable the SSL/TLS with external configuration which can be provided during the application startup.
The application should support all crud operations for http and https.

```
## SSL
server.port=8081
server.ssl.key-store=file:C:\\Users\\karthik\\hnm.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=C*GSYS
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
```

These properties are defined in application.properties

```
#Spring Security
security.require-ssl=false
```

Since the above property is deprecated, how can i achieve it without using the profiles.

Comment: I found the solution in this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324700/enable-https-with-self-signed-certificate-in-spring-boot-2-0

Answer (score 3):

To disable SSL, you can use:

```java
server.ssl.enabled = false
```

Have a look at the [server properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties) documentation for details.

Comment: For some reason it is not working with application.properties

Answer (score 0):

The properties if defined in application.yml

```
server:
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: file:C:\\Users\\karthik\\hnm.p12
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    key-store-password: C*GSYS
```

enabling and disabling the HTTPS can be achieved without code change.
Tried and tested in `Sprint boot 2.2.4.RELEASE`